# How to enrich azure b2c token with custom claims using api connectors and asp net core web api

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

I have a user flow B2C_1_singupsingin1
I added an api connector, embed it in this stream and the endpoint url for the API call.
Used article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-api-connector-token-enrichment?pivots=b2c-user-flow

It is clear from the article that the API connector materializes as an HTTP POST request, sending custom attributes.

My web api has an endpoint with the code:

```
[HttpPost("enrich")]
public IActionResult Enrich([FromBody] JsonElement body)
{
    var responseProperties = new Dictionary<string, object> //for example
    {
        { "version", "1.0.0" },
        { "action", "Continue" },
        { "postalCode", "12349" },
        { "userId", 123 } 
    };

    return new JsonResult(responseProperties) { StatusCode = 200 };
}
```

When I start a custom flow everything works, I get to that endpoint in api.
But there is a problem JsonElement body does't contain custom attributes. Inside I see `body.ValueKind = Undefined`.
Tell me what am I doing wrong?

Also, after all, I wanted to add a custom "userId" claim with some value from my database.
So that it is contained in the token issued in the subsequent. Would the code above be correct for this?

Comment: I don't think it works. It's in preview, I've got the same situation. The audit logs in B2C show the continuation and its marked as success, but the claim is not added to the token.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is fine. Just add "**extension_**" in front of postalCode and userId.

```
    [HttpPost("log")]
    public IActionResult Log([FromBody] JsonElement body)
    {

        var responseProperties = new Dictionary<string, object> 
        {
            { "version", "1.0.0" },
            { "action", "Continue" },
            { "extension_Role", "admin" },
        };

        return new JsonResult(responseProperties) { StatusCode = 200 };
    }
```

In my Azure AD B2C I have a custom attribute called "Role".

But in debug mode I saw that for all the custom attributes **extension_** is set as prefix...

So by adding this to responseProperties it seems to be working.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem a long time ago, but maybe my experience will help someone.
First part of the question:

> "The body of the JsonElement contains no custom attributes. Inside I
> see body.ValueKind = Undefined"

What was the problem.
To support HTTP Patch requests, I added the NewtonsoftJson package and configuration to Startup:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(x => 
{
   x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

But I didn’t consider that AddNewtonsoftJson replaces the System.Text.Json-based input and output formatters used for formatting all JSON content. Because of this I was getting the above problem. [Solution from Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

The solution to the second part of the question with a custom claims was provided by *Steffen*. You just need to add **extension_** prefix to claim.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to guide working code reference for this so in case if someone needs it will help them.

As of 2024 Jan, the API connector used in Azure AD B2C is stable (though it shows as a preview) and we can Enrich the external claims.

Here is the overview of how to do this.

1. In Azure AD B2C's custom attributes, create the attribute as needed.
2. In userflow, E.g. SUSI (signup signin user flow), pick these created attributes in application claims
3. Create Azure function or any http function (should be much fast responsive one) that can be called by API connector.
4. Cofigure API connector to call this function with Basic Authentication
5. Hook up this in SUSI userflow

Now, before the token is generated the claims are added. Fallow the code in details from GitHub repo

https://github.com/learnsmartcoding/e-commerce-smartcarthub-azure-functions

video link for reference: https://youtu.be/KKkgKMMyZFw

E.g.
SignUpValidation function is invoked by Azure AD B2C via API Connector. This call is invoked before the token is generated and issued to the caller. This function receives the request, talks to other functions to create a user and its role in the database and then returns the UserId and User Roles in the claims.